# Not matching md5 passwords

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using a jQuery datagrid plugin to make an easy tool to edit my User's table in the admin area of a site.  I store the passwords as md5() when the user registers.  When ever I attempt to update the table, it is rehashing the password, thus making it unusable.  I've tried several methods of verifying the password is the same as the one in the database, but none of them seem to be working.

Here is my update code:

PHP

```
<?php
require_once("../class/TimeClock.class.php");

$tc = new TimeClock();
$id = $_POST['id'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$active = $_POST['active'];
$role = $_POST['role'];
$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];

if($tc->validatePass($id, $password)) {
try {
    $tc->connect();
    $query = $tc->dbh->prepare("UPDATE us_users SET username=:username,email=:email,active=:active,role=:role,emp_id=:emp_id WHERE id=:id");
    $query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':email' => $email, ':active' => $active, ':role' => $role, ':emp_id' => $emp_id, ':id' => $id));
    $tc->close();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    throw new Exception('Something bad happened' . $e->getMessage());
}
} else {
try {
    $password = md5($password);
    $tc->connect();
    $query = $tc->dbh->prepare("UPDATE us_users SET username=:username,password=:password,email=:email,active=:active,role=:role,emp_id=:emp_id WHERE id=:id");
    $query->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => $password, ':email' => $email, ':active' => $active, ':role' => $role, ':emp_id' => $emp_id, ':id' => $id));
    $tc->close();
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    throw new Exception('Something bad happened' . $e->getMessage());
}
}

echo json_encode(array(
'id' => $id,
'username' => $username,
'password' => $password,
'email' => $email,
'active' => $active,
'role' => $role,
'emp_id' => $emp_id
));
?>
```

My validatePasss() function:

PHP

```
function validatePass($id, $pass) {
    try {
    $this->connect();
    $result = $this->dbh->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM us_users WHERE id=:id");
    $result->execute(array(':id' => $id));
    $userObj = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    } catch( PDOException $e) {
        throw new Exception('Something bad happened' . $e->getMessage());
        die();
    }
    if($pass == $userObj['password']) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    $this->close();
}
```

I know that the mysql_ code is out dated, however, when I try to use PDO it throws errors, I think it is related to the component or something.

Thank you for any assistance you can provide.

**EDIT:** Changed the function to pure PDO, and here is an image of the datagrid so you see that the passwords are stored as a hash, and, unless changed, should be passed to the update script as a match to what is in the database.

http://www.bolinconstruction.com/timeclock/datagrid.png

Comment: What errors?  Can't provide much assistance if you can't give us a clue.

Comment: Duh, sorry.  The code is never showing that passwords match, and instead is always returning the md5() password instead, therefore making it impossible for a user to log in if I have edited any details.

Comment: aren't you comparing plaintext password from form with md5 stored in db ?

Comment: the password that is getting passed from the form should either be the previous password stored as md5 hash (in which case it should return "match") or a new password that should then get hashed and stored in the db.

Comment: The two pieces of code seem to be have been written by two different people: the `validatePass` method properly uses PDO and prepared statements, while the code above it is terrible: not only does it use `$_REQUEST` (bad), it suppresses errors - that `@` in front of the function call (worse) and is wide open to SQL injection (worst\).

Comment: @NullUserException For some reason when I attempt to use PDO on the update, it breaks the component.  This is not going into a production environment until I can migrate all SQL queries to PDO; however, for the time being, I"m just trying to get the code to function as I would expect it to.

Comment: @FireCrakcer37 What do you mean by "breaks the component"? Show us the PDO code and any errors it was spitting out. Also, you have to is remove that `@` from `@mysql_query`.

Comment: Is this an admin script you can use to modify user details? If so, there's a problem with your logic: you're validating the password. Unless you know the user's password and send it with the rest of the data, password validation will *always* fail, causing it to always reset the password to whatever `$_REQUEST['password']` is.

Comment: I updated the script to use PDO :)

Unless I change the password field $_POST['password'] should hold the hash of the old password (the exact same string I pull out of the database in the first place).  My logic is, if $displayedPassword == $databasePassword THEN don't update password.  Is there another way to go about doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was actually simple after I thought it through.  In the initial code, I was polling the database for the password of the username that was submitted with the form.  If the username was changed, then of course the query would fail, and thus change the password.  By setting it up to poll the database based on ID instead, the problem seems to have corrected itself.  Thank you all for your help, I never would have figured this out without you guys.

Answer (score 1):

In your `validatePass()` function, you must hash the password before comparing

```
if(md5($pass) == $userObj['password']) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

You could do the same in your query

```
select id
from from us_users
where username = :username and password = :password
```

and then

```
$result->execute(array(':username' => $username, ':password' => md5($password)));
```

and test for number of rows > 0.

Comment: The password is already a Hash, unless it has been changed in the form.  Basically, unless I change the password field on the form, it is passing back the same value it pulled from the database in the first place.  Using firbug, I have determined this to be true; however, it is still changing the password on every update.

Comment: Trusting a md5 hash coming from the internet is the same as storing unhashed passwords in the database.